# Referring to a character in a text as 'The [Last Name]'

Tags: definite-articles, names, surnames

I have scoured the internet and am yet to find the reason why.
I am in process of helping a friend out and would like to know why we refer to them as 'the [Last Name]'. Eg. 'The Beaker slid across the room.'

Edit as requested:

"As the messenger came to run up to the small village off in the corner of Cearundel, he looked for **the Ludovicus**."

"As soon as it arrived, it was opened with eager hands by **the Herand**,[...]"

Comment: Can you add some examples to your question please?  This isn't a common usage.

Comment: Your examples seem more like roles or titles than names.  Are you certain they are names, rather than, for example, "John Smith, the village Herand"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names are not usually preceded by a "the" in English, although they often are in other languages (it's called the *preproprial definite article*).

That said, there was an old convention in Scottish and Irish English of using "the" plus the family or clan name when referring to the head of a family or clan.

For [example](https://books.google.com/books?id=T24l6YzliL8C&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=ancient%20scottish%20definite%20article%20name&source=bl&ots=0pu6NBWRmT&sig=lKMrY-DacXPsovfr9hvCt0jZuBc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk5bSiipHOAhWIOj4KHR9QALYQ6AEIJzAD#v=snippet&q=Mac%20Dermot&f=false),

> - the Mac Dechet
> - the Mac Dermot
> - the O'Connor Don
> - the O'Donaghue

The passage you cite might be playing on this old convention. But impossible to tell until you give us some more information.

Another option is that in the world of the text, names like "Beaker", "Herand", and "Ludovicus" are acting like *code names* or *role-type names*. These are often prefixed with definite articles, as in:

> - The Red Swan responded to my call for help. [**code name**]
> - The Hamlet gave a great performance last night, but the Ophelia did terribly. [**roll-type names**]

There are a few other contexts in English where you would use a definite article before a name, but they don't seem to fit your example passages (see comments, below).

Comment: there are another possibilities, it's when there are several people of the same name and/or we're not sure if the person exist, also if the person has become household name. for example: "I found a letter from Caesar yesterday.  -You mean THE Caesar?" Or  taken from a history book "A case can be made to support either Louis the Pious (778–840), the son of Charlemagne, or Louis the German (804– 76), Charlemagne's grandson, as the “Ludovicus” in question."

Comment: @P.Obertelli, you're absolutely right. I didn't mention those because they don't seem to fit the OP's example passages.